# Regex for ip addres v4 with optional port

Tags: javascript, html, regex, port, ip-address

I had problem to detect input with pattern for ip address v4 with optional port

I had found just pattern for ip address v4 only

this is code only for ipv4

```
/\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\b/
```

i'd expected regex can read, example:
192.168.11.11 or 192.168.11.11:8000

Comment: https://www.regextester.com/97040

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands, your regex will match the IP address. If you also want it to match the port, just add in a optional non-capturing before the final word boundary to pick up `:` followed by `0-4` digits:

```
(?::\d{0,4})?\b
```

This would create the following:

```
/\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)(?::\d{0,4})?\b/
```

Which matches both of your inputs:

```js
const regex = /\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)(?::\d{0,4})?\b/;

console.log(regex.test('192.168.11.11'));
console.log(regex.test('192.168.11.11:8000'));
```

Comment: Works like Charms!